# Dispatch Barrier on Main Queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, asyncdisplaykit

So I am reading Facebook's awesome *[AsyncDisplayKit](https://github.com/facebook/AsyncDisplayKit)* source code. Specifically, I am reading the implementation behind *ASDealloc2MainObject*. One thing caught my eye.

In [*_AS-objc-internal.h*, line 423 to 424](https://github.com/facebook/AsyncDisplayKit/blob/master/AsyncDisplayKit/Private/_AS-objc-internal.h#L423), there is the programmer dispatching some task onto the main queue.

```
        dispatch_barrier_async_f(dispatch_get_main_queue(), self,           \
            _objc_deallocOnMainThreadHelper);                               \
```

As is the case of other dispatch barrier functions, the barrier logic from `dispatch_barrier_async_f()`only makes sense if it's dealing with a custom concurrent queue. For global concurrent queues and the main queue, it'll act just like `dispatch_async_f()` with the barrier having no effect.

So why using barrier here?

Comment: In my view, using 'barrier' with the main queue isn't relevant because a serial queue executes one operation at a time anyway. 'Dispatch_async' should be enough to get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a mistake to me. At best, they're trying to signal intent and remind the programmer "hey, this thing is serial", but that seems pretty dubious.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree.

Comment: From Apple's gcd source code I found a possible explanation. Please see my answer. I'm still not quite sure though.

Comment: on a serial queue, every item is a barrier item and dispatch_barrier_async_f() and dispatch_async_f() are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a possible explanation: `dispatch_async_f()` calls `dispatch_barrier_async_f()` under the hood if the queue passed in has the width of concurrency set to 1.

The [implementation](http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/trac/browser/trunk/src/queue.c) of `dispatch_async_f()` looks like this:

```
DISPATCH_NOINLINE
    void
    dispatch_async_f(dispatch_queue_t dq, void *ctxt, dispatch_function_t func)
    {
            dispatch_continuation_t dc;

            // No fastpath/slowpath hint because we simply don't know
            if (dq->dq_width == 1) {
                    return dispatch_barrier_async_f(dq, ctxt, func);
            }

            dc = fastpath(_dispatch_continuation_alloc_cacheonly());
            if (!dc) {
                    return _dispatch_async_f_slow(dq, ctxt, func);
            }

            dc->do_vtable = (void *)DISPATCH_OBJ_ASYNC_BIT;
            dc->dc_func = func;
            dc->dc_ctxt = ctxt;

            // No fastpath/slowpath hint because we simply don't know
            if (dq->do_targetq) {
                    return _dispatch_async_f2(dq, dc);
            }

            _dispatch_queue_push(dq, dc);
    }
```